# Какие инструменты использовать для создания галереи?

Tags: авторизация

У меня накопилось приличное количество личных фото и видео. Теперь я хочу на своём сайте реализовать галерею с системой прав доступа.

Сейчас у меня в голове это выглядит так:
я сам заполняю БД логинами и паролями для всех, с кем я хочу поделиться. У каждого "аккаунта" должны быть права или их отсутствие на просмотр тех или иных папок с контентом (фото\видео). На сайте отображается только контент, соответствующий правам текущего пользователя. Видео заливаю на ютуб с доступом по ссылке. C местом хранения фото пока не определился (тоже хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение).

Опыта у меня не много и я пока не очень ориентируюсь во всём разнообразии фреймворков. Пока на примете Yii.

Comment: vk.com / facebook.com

Comment: @tCode Я вообще не очень доверяю социальным сетям в этом вопросе. К тому же вижу в этом возможность получить полезный опыт.

Comment: Какой-то движок для сайта используется? Если да, то скорее всего, решение для авторизации уже есть. Если нет, то можно посмотреть опять же, в сторону готовых решений/библиотек.

Насчет места хранения - можно вроде бы использовать гугло-диск и яндекс-диск для таких целей, хотя могу ошибаться.

Comment: @BlackWitcher Не используется. Вот про готовые решения и библиотеки мне было бы очень интересно узнать. Как такое гуглить?

Comment: [Так](https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&safe=off&q=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0) например, и [первая ссылка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/173313/), в качестве одного из многих вариантов.

Comment: Если у вас статичный сайт, и вы хотите добавить туда новый функционал (галерею), то здесь есть 2 пути, которые, думаю, вы понимаете - или развивать свой сайт дальше, или воспользоваться чем-то готовым. В любом случае опыт вы получите, просто он будет разным. Лично сам бы я выделил бы на хостинге поддомен, папку для хранения файлов движка, и поэксперементировал бы с разными решениями, привязывая их на этот поддомен. Либо использовал бы denwer или OpenServer, что бы поиграться локально с разными вариантами. Когда нашел бы то, что нужно - применил бы в качестве рабочего решения уже в сети.

Comment: А еще по ссылке на статью про Кокен почитайте комментарии. У многих людей, как я понял, итоговые задачи сходны с вашей. И в комментариях есть ссылки на разные аналогичные сервисы/ресурсы/проекты. Статья 13-го года, потому учитывайте это - что-то могло обновиться, что-то поменяться, а что-то просто умереть.